# how to overlay two sns.catplots

Tags: seaborn, catplot

I need to overlay two sns.catplots
One is of kind='box' and the other is kind='swarm' as follows:

```
gbox= sns.catplot( x="Emotion",y="Threshold",hue="Group", col = 'Task',
               data=indata,palette ["skyblue","salmon"], kind="box", showmeans='True', meanline = 'True', height=6, aspect=0.8, boxprops={'facecolor':'None'}, edgecolor='gray')

sns.catplot( x="Emotion",y="Threshold",hue="Group", col = 'Task',
             data=indata, palette=["skyblue","salmon"], kind="swarm",ax=gbox.axes)
```

I have tried taking the axes from one and feeding into the other catplot, but I receive an error as below.  How can I fix this?

```
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-74-7a05cc88a396> in <module>
     17 
     18 gbox =sns.catplot( x="Emotion",y="Threshold",hue="Group", col = 'Task',
---> 19             data=indata,palette=["skyblue","salmon"],kind="swarm",ax=gbox.axes)
     20 
     21 #plt.show(gbox)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/seaborn/categorical.py in catplot(x, y, hue, data, row, col, col_wrap, estimator, ci, n_boot, units, order, hue_order, row_order, col_order, kind, height, aspect, orient, color, palette, legend, legend_out, sharex, sharey, margin_titles, facet_kws, **kwargs)
   3753 
   3754     # Draw the plot onto the facets
-> 3755     g.map_dataframe(plot_func, x, y, hue, **plot_kws)
   3756 
   3757     # Special case axis labels for a count type plot

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/seaborn/axisgrid.py in map_dataframe(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
    818 
    819             # Draw the plot
--> 820             self._facet_plot(func, ax, args, kwargs)
    821 
    822         # Finalize the annotations and layout

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/seaborn/axisgrid.py in _facet_plot(self, func, ax, plot_args, plot_kwargs)
    836 
    837         # Draw the plot
--> 838         func(*plot_args, **plot_kwargs)
    839 
    840         # Sort out the supporting information

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/seaborn/categorical.py in swarmplot(x, y, hue, data, order, hue_order, dodge, orient, color, palette, size, edgecolor, linewidth, ax, **kwargs)
   2989                        linewidth=linewidth))
   2990 
-> 2991     plotter.plot(ax, kwargs)
   2992     return ax
   2993 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/seaborn/categorical.py in plot(self, ax, kws)
   1444     def plot(self, ax, kws):
   1445         """Make the full plot."""
-> 1446         self.draw_swarmplot(ax, kws)
   1447         self.add_legend_data(ax)
   1448         self.annotate_axes(ax)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/seaborn/categorical.py in draw_swarmplot(self, ax, kws)
   1374         # Set the categorical axes limits here for the swarm math
   1375         if self.orient == "v":
-> 1376             ax.set_xlim(-.5, len(self.plot_data) - .5)
   1377         else:
   1378             ax.set_ylim(-.5, len(self.plot_data) - .5)

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'set_xlim'
```

Thank you for your help!
SJ

Answer (score 0):

In theory, using the .map and .map_dataframe methods should work, but

- it fails when you do not want to use the same dimensionality across the plots that you are trying to overlay (for instance, using a different hue parameter for the first and second plot to show data split in different ways but overlaid)

> EDIT it sort of works but only when sns.FacetGrid is first initiated independently with `col/row` argument, and the `hue` parameter is passed in individual .map_dataframe functions? I did not explore every combination, this is a bit hacky and inconsistently working in anyway.

- it is impossible to control the zorder in which the two plots are overlaid (no matter in which order I call g.map(sns.pointplot, x, y1) and g.map(sns.pointplot, x, y2), the order between y1 and y2 will always be the same!!)

> EDIT this is at least the case for pointplot, see issue [#2339](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/2339#issuecomment-718977176)

Ideally, the catplot/lmplot/relplot/displot functions **should allow a grid argument** (equivalent to the ax argument of the other seaborn functions)!

Answer (score 0):

First create the catplot that sets up the facet grid and then loop over the axes and plot the overlay plots on them individually. So roughly like this:

```py
gbox = sns.catplot(
    data=indata,
    x="Emotion",
    y="Threshold",
    hue="Group",
    col='Task',
    palette["skyblue", "salmon"],
    kind="box",
    showmeans='True',
    meanline='True',
    height=6,
    aspect=0.8,
    boxprops={'facecolor': 'None'},
    edgecolor='gray',
)

for i, task in enumerate(indata['Task'].unique()):
    sns.swarmplot(                            # Note: just one swarmplot
        data=indata[indata['Task'] == task],  # select the relevant data subset
        ax=gbox.axes[i],                      # append to the relevant axis
        x="Emotion",
        y="Threshold",
        hue="Group",
        palette=["skyblue", "salmon"],
    )
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot pass an `ax=` parameter to `catplot`. You will need to create the `FacetGrid` "by hand".

Something like this: (untested because you did not provide data)

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(data=indata, hue="Group", col ='Task',
                  palette=["skyblue","salmon"])
g.map(sns.boxplot, x="Emotion", y="Threshold", showmeans='True', meanline = 'True',
                   height=6, aspect=0.8, boxprops={'facecolor':'None'}, edgecolor='gray')

g.map(sns.swarmplot, x="Emotion", y="Threshold")
```